# Как получить продукты в OpenCart 2.3.х из нескольких категорий

Tags: opencart

Есть массив id категорий, как записать в другой массив все продукты из этих категорий?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модель - Каталог - product.php в нём есть метод getProducts, с помощью которого можно получить товары из категории:

```
 $data['filter_category_id'] = '1'; // где 1 это id категории 
 $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($data);
```

НО проблема в том, что можно вывести товары только из одной категории. Вам необходимо создать другой метод, на основе этого, где бы можно было передать массив категорий.

А именно, в этом методе есть код:

```
if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
    if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
        $sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
    } else {
        $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
    }

    if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
        $implode = array();

        $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

        foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
            $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
        }

        $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
    }
}
```

Где это строку

`$sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";`

можно заменить на эту:

`$sql .= " AND p2c.category_id IN ('" . implode(', ', $array_categories) . "')";` // где $array_categories - будет вашим массивом идов категорий

---

Это сырой код, в вашем случаи код может быть другой, но сам принцип думаю понятен.